# Anon Functions Return True

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I don't get anon. functions.  And I am continually have to write little loops to find certain values in arrays.  I want to know if I can write something like the following:

```
$isItTrue = function() {
  foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if($key == "foobar") retu
  }
};
```

Sorry  I don't have a better example but this is the general gist.  Is there a better way to do this? It seems needless to write a named function just to find out something so trivial.

Comment: Well, at least the function syntax should be valid...

Comment: What do you want to receive? Your example is not complete. If you just want to check some values in an array both loops and anonymous functions are redundant.

Comment: I am aware the code above doesnt work, I was trying to illustrate what i'd like to do

Comment: Don't be afraid to use $some_value = call_user_func( function() use($v1,$etc){...}). Put the ugly stuff inside the function and leave your outer scope clean from ugly code and variables that shouldn't need to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does *not* work, but it is close. Take a look at this variant:

```
<?php

$isItTrue = function($key, $array) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array);
};

$input = [
 'a' => 0,
 'foobar' => 1,
 'b' => 2
];

var_dump($isItTrue('foobar', $input));
var_dump($isItTrue('nono', $input));
```

The output is:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

*Obviously you can directly use function `array_key_exists()` for this, but that is not the point. It is merely used as an example here...*

You won't come around implementing small helper functions where no ready-to-use utility functions exists in php. Though php offers a real wealth of such function it is obvious, that it has to be limited. Anonymous functions won't solve that need, that is not what they are for. Their power lies elsewhere: you can define multiple and hand them over as "black boxes" to wherever you want them to be used. That means the runtime environment does not need to know which function is executed. It does not need to refer directly to it. It does not need to know the function name.

A typical example would be a catalog of something, maybe "features", that also offers a "validation function". At run time, the code using the function is not interested in what validation function to use. It uses the catalog, in there some function is defined which is used for the validation. Another form of code encapsulation beside OOP, if you put it that way.

Comment: Thanks! I get that now.  I was looking to make a quick decision, without creating a whole new function (and name).  Thank you for your very helpful answer though!